# SQLAlchemy filter for attributes containing all characters of substring, regardless of order

Tags: python, regex, flask, sqlalchemy

I am having issues trying to set up an SQLAlchemy query for my Flask app.

What I want to do is query the database for all usernames that contain the characters from an input in any order.

I know you can use `User.query.filter(User.username.contains(input))` to check if a substring is present, but the substring must be in order for that.

For example, with that expression if my input was `Marcus` then it would work, filtering for my username `MarcusWilliams`. That is great, but I also want it to work if I have a username that contains all of the characters of the input regardless of their order.

For example, I would want all `Marcus`, `sucraM`, and `MiWl` to filter for my username, because in all cases the characters in the input are all present in the username.

I have tried a couple of things, such as checking if the set of characters from the input is a subset of the username set of characters, but the logic within the SQLAlchemy query is limited so that did not work.

Sorry if there is a simple solution that I am missing, any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

With the help of the answer from @shipskin and with some edits I have made some progress.

By doing this:

```
User.query.filter(User.username.op('regexp')(".*".join(list(input))))
```

I am now able to match characters which have the all of the character in the username, but there is still a problem. The characters still have to be in the order they appear in the username, for example `MWil` would work, but `WMill` does not work, because the characters don't appear in that order in my username.

Comment: So the target string must contain all of the characters in the source string in any order, but do they need to be contiguous?

Comment: No they don't, I have update my question with another example of a source string.

Comment: If you can come up with a query that returns the username with its characters sorted alphabetically, e.g. 'randomguy` returned as 'adgmnoruy' then you could sort the source string, e.g. 'gord' as 'dgor' and use … WHERE sorted_username LIKE '%d%g%o%r%'. Repeated characters might complicate things, as would case-sensitivity (if you wanted it).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.regexp_match

You could do something like `Users.query.filter(User.username.op('regexp')('|'.join([c for c in input]))` or generate a better regex.

Comment: Thank you, but this seems to be matching to anything that contains at least one of the characters from the input. I need it to match if all of them are present and not match if any of them are not present. For example what you have done was also match my username to ```Mzz``` simply because the input contains an M.

Comment: This still may be a good starting point though, I'll keep trying similar things

Comment: I see, how about using brackets to match all the characters in the input and then exclude all characters not in the input using a caret (^)? I would suggest using a regex builder like https://regex101.com/ good luck!

Comment: I got it working but had still had a problem, check the question, it was updated.